# Map Loading is Slow

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps Javascript API v3 in `WebBrowser` control in my WPF Application.

My application was working fine until the customer one day reported that the map is loading very slowly. On debugging, I came to know that the following line is taking time:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

The following are my map options where cPoint is a Google Location

```
mapOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: cPoint,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.Map
    }
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

I have no clue as to what to search for or how to fix this. Any pointers would be really helpful

Comment: there is no such `mapTypeId`  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MapTypeId

Comment: @geocodezip: My map doesn't freeze every 30 seconds. But the answer that is mentioned in the other question fixed my problem. I added the API version and it works fine now. Thank you